# Graficar datos con Google Charts, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente problema: quiero mostrar datos que obtengo desde mi base de datos con `google charts`, pero cuando intento hacerlo me aparece la pagina en blanco, este es mi codigo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Inicial', 'churrasco cuadril', 'merma'],
     <?php
      echo "[".$r['inicial'].", ".$r['churrasco_cuadril'].", ".$r['merma']."]";
     ?>
     //['2004',  1000, 400]
   ]);

   var options = {
     title: 'Company Performance',
     curveType: 'function',
     legend: { position: 'bottom' }
   };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Estoy buscando por internet alguna solución pero no encuentro data para resolverlo.

Todos los datos que quiero traer son de tipo decimal.

Comment: ¿Has cargado el script `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`? ¿Existe un elemento con id `curve_chart`? ¿El resultado de `echo "[".$r['inicial'].", ".$r['churrasco_cuadril'].", ".$r['merma']."]";` es igual a `['2004',  1000, 400]`?

Comment: hola @Marcos, el script si esta cargado en la cabecera, la linea ['2004', 1000, 400] viene con el codigo que saque desde la pagina de google, igual esta comentada

Answer (score 2):

Veo 2 problemas:

1. La primera son con las concatenaciones.
2. El tipo de `dato`, ya que si intentas pasarle un valor de tipo `string`, en donde **REALMENTE** espera un tipo de dato numérico, este nunca sera reflejada en el gráfico, ocasionando que nunca cargue el `script`. Te recomiendo revisar si tus datos son del tipo de dato numérico (**int** o **float**).

Ahora, implementé tu problema y la solución a la cual he llegado es la siguiente:

```
<?php 
    $arreglo = array(
        array(
            'inicial' => '2006',
            'churrasco_cuadril' => 3000,
            'merma' => 200
        ),
        array(
            'inicial' => '2004',
            'churrasco_cuadril' => 1000,
            'merma' => 400
        )
    );

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Inicial', 'Churrasco Cuadril', 'Merma'],
          [<?php echo $arreglo[0]['inicial'] ?>, <?php echo $arreglo[0]['churrasco_cuadril'] ?>, <?php echo $arreglo[0]['merma'] ?>],
          [<?php echo $arreglo[1]['inicial'] ?>, <?php echo $arreglo[1]['churrasco_cuadril'] ?>, <?php echo $arreglo[1]['merma'] ?>]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

***Notas:***

- El `array` que puse en el ejemplo, son para simular tus datos obtenidos de una base de datos, lo que tendrías que hacer es recorrer tu arreglo y colocar que datos quieres mostrar pero ya eso es otro tema.
- Si la página te aparece en blanco, significa que hay un error en el **script**, la cual nunca se ejecuta y no añade nada al `<div>` en el cual va el resultado.

Espero haberte ayudado.